# Object Comparison with same value

Tags: javascript

I am checking obeject comparison, below two instance gives 'false' and anyone can explain why?

```
var a = {x:7, y:9};
var b = {x:7, y:9};

console.log(a==b);   //false
console.log(a===b);  //false
```

Comment: lodash : _.isEqual(a, b);
// -> true

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not a primitive value. `a` is just refers to an object and `b` refers to another object. Both are holding reference of different `object`.
Both can not be same